# Looking for difference between xdmp:value() vs xdmp:eval()

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Can someone provide a better explanation of the `xdmp:eval()` and `xdmp:value()` functions?

I had tried to follow the Developer API. However, I am not really satisfied with the instances and it's a bit vague for me. I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand those functions and their differences with examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both functions are for executing strings of code dynamically, but [`xdmp:value`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value) is evaluated against the current context, such that if you have variables defined in the current scope or modules declared, you can reference them without redeclaring them.

[`xdmp:eval`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval) necessitates the creation of an entirely new context that has no knowledge of the context calling [`xdmp:eval`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval). One must define a new XQuery prolog, and variables from the main context are passed to the [`xdmp:eval`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval) call as parameters and declared as external variables in the eval script.

Generally, if you can use [`xdmp:value`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value), it's probably the best choice; however, [`xdmp:eval`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval) has some capabilities that [`xdmp:value`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value) doesn't, namely everything defined in the `<options>` argument. Through these options, it's possible to control the user executing the query, the database it's executed against, transaction mode, etc.

There is another function for executing dynamic strings: [`xdmp:unpath`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unpath), and it's similar to [`xdmp:value`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:value), but more limited in that it can only execute XPath.

Comment: To be a little more precise: `xdmp:unpath` accepts whatever `xdmp:path` produces. That is a rather limited subset of XPath, mostly child steps and position predicates. Also worth mentioning here are `xdmp:spawn` and `xdmp:invoke` that behave similar to `xdmp:eval`, and create a new context. Relatively new though are `xdmp:spawn-function`, and `xdmp:invoke-function`, which take along the current context.